# MongoDB modify the array of objects field by element number without findAndModify or update query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem with updating / modifying the Mongoose embed document.

My function iterate over each document in the collection one-by-one via `EachASync` cursor:

```js
//inside async function
.EachASync(async MongoDoc => { //<= Mongo Document type, not lean!
  //other logic modifiying other fields

  const names = ['name1'] //it could be multiple values

  
  for (const element of names ) {
    //findIndex in MongoDoc.filter.realms <= array of objects
    const index = MongoDoc.filter.realms.findIndex(realm => realm.name === element)
    //I want to update the specific object property 'time' inside array by index
    MongoDoc.filter.realms[index].time = Date.now()
  }
  await MongoDoc.save()
}
```

Actually I modifying the whole document, but I **also** want to update the specific nested object field, which contains the array of the object field.

The schema for the selected fields:

```
// Schema
{
  _id: MongoID,
  //many other fields,
  filter: { // <= parent field
    realm: [{ // <= parent object
      name: String,
      time: Number, //the value that I want to update by index
    }]
  }
}
```

### Example

```
{
  _id: 1,
  filter: {
    realms: [
      {
        name: "name1", 
        time: 1, //modify this values via it's index number 
        // in this case it's 0
        // via MongoDoc.filter.realms, without updateOne or findAndUpdate
      },
      {
        name: "name2",
        time: 2,
      },
      {
        name: "name3",
        time: 3,
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So the question is: How to achieve my results appropriately? Without using `findAndUpdate` or `updateOne`? According to [this article](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/), it's somehow possible.

Also, what's the optimal solution? To update the necessary object value by index? Like:

```
MongoDoc.filter.realms[index].time = Date.now()
```

Or rebuild the whole array of objects, by copy / mutating the original one?

Comment: Can you post a document example and expected output please?

Comment: @J.F .Yeah, no problem, will be updated in a couple of minutes. I thought to post in on MongoPlayground, but unfortunately, it's not their use case

Comment: So I'm assuming you don't want to use: `"$set": { "filter.realms.0.time": newValue }`. But, because you don't want or you think you cannot set `"filter.realms."+index+".time"` in a query?

Comment: @J.F. I want to use `"filter.realms."+index+".time"` but I am not sure how to do it correctly. Also, if `MongoDoc.filter.realms.$set()` works, I'd like to use it too. I don't have experience with that, so that's why I am asking about it. I also haven't find anything on SO, about this case. All the examples are about `findAndModify` or `update` queries, not modifying the existing Mongoose document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen your code and I think you are wrong when you want to update by index.

You think you need the index because you know where is the object whit 'name1' using `findIndex()`. But this is not a good way.

Your code loop trough the entire collection, document by document, and look for the array index where `name` field is 'name1', 'name2' or 'name3'. And then update the `time` value with the actual date, right?

You can do this with a simple `mongo` query without loop or JS functions. Check [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GVW3RaidgsF)

```js
db.collection.update({
  "_id": 1,
  
},
{
  "$set": {
    "filter.realms.$[element].time": new Date()
  }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    {
      "$or": [
        {
          "element.name": "name1"
        },
        {
          "element.name": "name2"
        },
        {
          "element.name": "name3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

Using `arrayFilters` with an `$or` condition you can modify the attribute `time` which `name` filed is one of the given.

Also the `element` 'variable' from `arrayFilters` is used into `$set` to update the specific index.

Check is the behaviour is as you expected.

Answer (score 1):

The current working code is stll:

```
  for (const element of names ) {
    const index = MongoDoc.filter.realms.findIndex(realm => realm.name === element)
    MongoDoc.filter.realms[index].time = Date.now()
  }
  await MongoDoc.save()
```

but I also found, that array of object fields in the original Mongoose Documents (not `lean()` results) are a bit different somehow. And some `Array.prototype` methods on them are not working appropriately.

Sometimes it's better to clone the field's value to a new array via spread `[...array]` operators and work with this new variable directly, and then completely overwrite the field.